# added a character after the 6th comma using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a csv file like below:

```
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Elementary Algebra 34,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Reading Comprehension 97,Sentence Skills 104,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115,
```

If the phrase 'Reading Comprehension' does not exist in the line, add a comma after the 5th comma

I'm trying to figure this out using AWK, but cant seem to figure it out. I'm assuming Ill need to do use gsub to loop, but I cant figure out how to add a ',' after $5

The end goal would look like this:

```
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,,Elementary Algebra 34,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Reading Comprehension 97,Sentence Skills 104,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/Reading Comprehension/! s/,/,,/5'
```

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '!/Reading Comprehension/ { $5 = $5 "," } 1'
```

Output:

```
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,,Elementary Algebra 34,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Reading Comprehension 97,Sentence Skills 104,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115,
```

Comment: Lovely.  I particularly like the `sed` version, which reminded me of a couple of features I had forgotten about (and so succinct!).

Comment: will this loop through multiple rows?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, sadly `s/.../.../N` is unique to `sed`.  It's quite awkward to do the same thing without it.

Comment: @moore1emu I'm not sure I understand your point.  It would apply to all matching rows, that's what `sed` and `awk` do.